# File attachment fixtures in Rails 7 not attaching correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7, system-testing

I am following the [guide here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/active_storage_overview.html#testing) verbatim but when I run my system tests, the file I am trying to upload does not seem to attach to my fixture. I believe I have everything set up correctly as I do see the uploaded file sitting in the temporary directory (tmp/storage_fixtures) so for whatever reason it's not attaching itself to the model. Here are my files:

**towns.yml**

```
toronto:
  id: 1
  name: Toronto
```

**blobs.yml**

```
toronto_map_image_blob: <%= ActiveStorage::FixtureSet.blob filename: "toronto_map.png", service_name: "test_fixtures" %>
```

**attachments.yml**

```
toronto_map_image:
  name: map_image
  record: toronto (Town)
  blob: toronto_map_image_blob
```

**config/storage.yml**

```
test_fixtures:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage_fixtures") %>
```

**town.rb**

```
class Town < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :map_image
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the issue I was having was defining an id within the towns fixture. Once I removed that and allowed the id to autogenerate, it worked. This explains why the attachments fixture was unable to properly assign itself to the town model (though I'm not sure why using a custom id doesn't work in this case and would appreciate insight if anyone has any).